# Scroll box lost padding!

Tags: css

I tried the following in IE8 and the latest versions of Firefox and Opera:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<style type="text/css">
div
{
background-color:#00FFFF;
width:300px;
height:82px;
overflow:auto;
white-space:nowrap;
padding:0 20px;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>

<div>
<img src="http://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-hUXeHq5OxEo/Thc7hFFv3gI/AAAAAAAAABQ/Yh7omR8iwzI/s800/thumb1.jpg" alt="">
<img src="http://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-hUXeHq5OxEo/Thc7hFFv3gI/AAAAAAAAABQ/Yh7omR8iwzI/s800/thumb1.jpg" alt="">
<img src="http://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-hUXeHq5OxEo/Thc7hFFv3gI/AAAAAAAAABQ/Yh7omR8iwzI/s800/thumb1.jpg" alt="">
<img src="http://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-hUXeHq5OxEo/Thc7hFFv3gI/AAAAAAAAABQ/Yh7omR8iwzI/s800/thumb1.jpg" alt="">
<img src="http://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-hUXeHq5OxEo/Thc7hFFv3gI/AAAAAAAAABQ/Yh7omR8iwzI/s800/thumb1.jpg" alt="">
<img src="http://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-hUXeHq5OxEo/Thc7hFFv3gI/AAAAAAAAABQ/Yh7omR8iwzI/s800/thumb1.jpg" alt="">
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

There's no padding on the right. What am I missing?

Many thanks in advance!

Mike

Comment: I'd prefer it to support IE8, but if you have a solution that works with others except IE8, I'd be glad to see it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a nice non IE8 solution. Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gna7q/

**CSS:**

```
div{
    background-color: #00FFFF;
    width: 300px;
    height: 82px;
    overflow: auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

div img:first-child{
    margin-left: 5px;
}
div img:last-child{
    margin-right: 5px;
}
```

Here is an IE8 supported version using jQuery/JavaScript. Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gna7q/1/

**jQuert/JavaScript:**

```
$(function () {
    $('div img:last-child').addClass('last-child')
});
```

**CSS:**

```
div{
    background-color:#00FFFF;
    width: 300px;
    height: 82px;
    overflow: auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

div img:first-child{
    margin-left: 5px;
}
div img.last-child{
    margin-right: 5px;
}
```

This version works by using the last-child selector in jQuery and adding a class of `.last-child` to it, so that the styling can all be kept in the CSS.

Comment: Nice, but it's a pity IE8 doesn't understand it. :( – Is there a way to add first and last child styles programmatically using JavaScript?

Comment: I have added the functionality using jQuery. The first-child selector is supported by IE8, just not last-child.

Comment: @rain You are welcome. If this is the correct answer, you should click the checkmark beside the answer (to mark it answered).

Answer (score 1):

instead use `white-space:nowrap` add an inner `div` with fixed width for the images like the following:

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="child">
        <img src="http://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-hUXeHq5OxEo/Thc7hFFv3gI/AAAAAAAAABQ/Yh7omR8iwzI/s800/thumb1.jpg" alt="">
        <img src="http://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-hUXeHq5OxEo/Thc7hFFv3gI/AAAAAAAAABQ/Yh7omR8iwzI/s800/thumb1.jpg" alt="">
        <img src="http://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-hUXeHq5OxEo/Thc7hFFv3gI/AAAAAAAAABQ/Yh7omR8iwzI/s800/thumb1.jpg" alt="">
        <img src="http://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-hUXeHq5OxEo/Thc7hFFv3gI/AAAAAAAAABQ/Yh7omR8iwzI/s800/thumb1.jpg" alt="">
        <img src="http://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-hUXeHq5OxEo/Thc7hFFv3gI/AAAAAAAAABQ/Yh7omR8iwzI/s800/thumb1.jpg" alt="">
        <img src="http://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-hUXeHq5OxEo/Thc7hFFv3gI/AAAAAAAAABQ/Yh7omR8iwzI/s800/thumb1.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
</div>
```

and css

```
#parent {
    background-color: #00FFFF;
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 0 20px;
    width: 300px;
}
#child {
    width: 520px;
}
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/TCYvw/

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the above is an example and my images array doesn't include a fixed number of images.